# WCF: Consume WebService using both certificate and username authentication

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, soap, certificate

I've been struggling for a while trying to consume a web-service hosted in a server **which I do not have control** (so I can't really do any configuration on the server part).

I've been using WCF to try to consume a web-service that has both Username/Password and Certificate authentication requirements (as well as a HTTPS connection).

The code that I have is this:

```
        EndpointAddress ea = new
                EndpointAddress("https://the.server.address");

        BasicHttpBinding bs = new BasicHttpBinding();

        bs.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
        bs.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType =
            HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

        //here if I put username I get a 'message is not signed' error. 
           If I put credentials I get an 'invalid username/password'.
        bs.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

        var svc = new myWebServiceClient(bs, ea);

        var request = new ObjectWS();

        svc.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
                                        StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
                                                 StoreName.Root,
                                X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber,
                                "the serial");

        svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "user";
        svc.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "pass";

        //the call to the method in the WS
        request= svc.getValue("param");
```

The problem is that, as I'm a newbie in WCF (and in WebServices in general), I don't actually know how to consume the web-service using both username and certificate authentication, nor do I know if that makes any sense at all.

In the line:

```
bs.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;
```

if I set the credential type to Certificate I get an Invalid Username/Password. in the other hand if I set it to Username I'll get a 'Message not signed error'.

I would really appreciate some feedback/help in this issue. Regards!

Comment: Can you get the Web.Config for the service?

Comment: If you can't get the entire Web.Config, at least try and get the binding security sections, that should help on how to configure your client.